# External bitmap concerns

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I am considering adding an external bitmap to my mdadm RAID6.  The benefits seem absolutely incredible in terms of rebuild time but I do have some concerns.

1. I didn't plan for it so I don't have much leftover space on my disks.  How much space does an external bitmap use?  Note that the filesystem is very large, 12x3TB RAID6.
2. How does the RAID initiate the external bitmap?  I would assume RAID devices are loaded before filesystems are mounted when a system reboots.  So if the filesystem containing the bitmap is not yet mounted, how does the RAID initiate?
3. What would happen if the external bitmap is lost?  Is it a large concern to have it on a single disk?  It doesn't seem to actually store data so I'm assuming if it is lost, the rebuild time would just take longer, it wouldn't actually cause any data loss on the RAID.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The bitmap is small by default; a few hundred kilobytes. You can scale it using --bitmap-chunks though (see mdadm(8)).

You can't place the external bitmap file on the RAID array itself.

You should be able to assemble a RAID array that has an external bitmap without the bitmap, but as far as I can tell there is no way to re-attach it afterwards. This isn't something I have tried though.

If the bitmap is lost, it should still be possible to assemble the array; however, if the single disk containing the bitmap fails while you're using the RAID array, interesting things may happen. I don't think this is a particularly well-tested scenario; I wouldn't dare to use a single disk to back a write intent bitmap if availability is important.